# How to avoid "Unable to read symbols for..." warning playing local UIWebView HTML files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that loads local HTML files. In one of those files/pages I have a video file embedded (with `<video>` tag) that plays correctly in both simulator and iPad, but in iPad I get this annoying warning message:

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.2/Symbols/System/Library/Internet
>   Plug-Ins/QuickTime
>   Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin"
>   (file not found).

The video plays correctly and audio is fine. The video format is `.m4v` that I made with QuickTime. I tried `.mp4` but I get even more warning messages with missing decoders.

Any idea what's going wrong? OR what can I do to get rid of this annoying message? By the way I load the HTML files to the UIWebView this way:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:html_string baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Thanx for the trouble :/

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen in the device? If not, it could be an old issue with the Simulator I've run into before myself. The problem that was one of my "Internet Plug-Ins" (for DivX) was giving the Simulator fits. I moved it to my desktop, re-launched the Simulator, and it was fine after that.

Comment: This is on an iPad, I assume by the error message? What version of iOS do you have on that device?